# how to set the thumbnail in react native

Tags: react-native, thumbnails

i have use thumbnail that gives error

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {StyleSheet, Text, View, Image,WebView} from 'react-native'
import Thumbnail from 'react-native-thumbnail-video';


export default class Screen3 extends  Component<{}>{

   constructor(props){
   super(props);
   }


render() 
{
  return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
     <Thumbnail url="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lgj3D5-jJ74" />
  </View>
)
}
}
```

in my project i have set the video thumbnail but that gives this error and i also use iframe but that give me same error ,please give me solution

Answer (score 1):

import Thumbnail like below, Its not default exported

```
import { Thumbnail } from 'react-native-thumbnail-video';
```